# how to create ligatures with 5+ elements?

Tags: fontforge, ligature

I am working on a font that requires extensive use of complex ligatures.

Everything works fine with ligatures composed of up to 4 characters, but if I create a ligature resulting from the combination of 5+ characters, when I use the font (exported as ttf) in Word and other standard text editors, the ligatures with 5+ elements are not displayed at all.

Is it a problem of fontforge, or a problem of the text editors?

And is there any way to solve it, perhaps using some command that I am missing?

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Comment: That is what i am wondering about - perhaps there is some command that I am missing? In that case, it would be a programming question, I think? :-)

Comment: But thx for the suggestion :-)